# How to add bubble event in bubble higharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to add event for highcharts bubble?

I have code https://jsfiddle.net/stachu/p4j5mng5/27/

```
           plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function (event) {
                                            $('#report').html(event.s);
                                                        }
                        }
                    },
                },
        bubble: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
                minSize:2,
                maxSize:42,
            },
        },
```

Code from plotOptions sections not working. Any idea to display s data from report div?

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5903) which appeared in 5.0.1 version. Use 5.0.0 version or the latest development version from github.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.0/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.0/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4j5mng5/29/