# Highcharts - Add URL on the bubble

Tags: url, text, highcharts, hyperlink

I want to add a link on a bubble.

It's ok with event :

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        click: function (event) {
          alert(event.point.link);
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

But it only works with dataLabels (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madvic/uobjj736/3/)). The link is on the text.

```
 dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: 'Info : {point.name}',
      },},
```

But I want to have a click event on the bubble.

Thanks of your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/madvic/uobjj736/3/

Comment: It looks like you should use `plotOptions.series.points.events.click` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click). But, it is looking like something is over-riding this.

Comment: It is a bug. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549961/how-to-add-bubble-event-in-bubble-higharts/40550860#40550860